# how to make an updating datagridview freely scrollable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've a `databound datagridiew` that I've implemented to update periodically. The problem is that when the `datagridviews` contents are updated the `datagridview` automatically jumps to display the last selected item.

I've implemented the following code so the top row is always displayed:

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
```

But it would be preferable if the entries in the `datagridview` could be scrolled freely whilst new entries are being added.

N.B. if I remove the line:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
```

The `datagridview` will still jump to display the last selected row so I'm guessing there is another property I need to set but it can't find it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987347/datagridview-keep-selections-after-datasource-is-changed

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I can't see how that helps?

Comment: There is an answer about selecting the row again after data source changed

Comment: I'm not changing the data source nor am I wanting to select any rows...